# Fiddler2 not capturing WSE2.0

Tags: fiddler, wse

I am trying to capture a message going to an external site using WSE2.0 and HTTPS but fiddler2 is not capturing the messages.  Is there any settings I need to do.  I have installed the FIDDLER2 certificate but its not working.  I am using Windows 7 currently, it was working on my Windows 8 machine but doesn't work on a colleagues Windows 8 machine.

Fiddler is capturing google + stackoverflow requests over Https tho.  It just not capturing WSE2.0, any ideas, I can't reveal the destination address for obvious reasons.

Comment: You need to configure your .NET application to proxy its traffic through Fiddler. http://fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-DOTNET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the problem was that I needed to change the Application Pool so it ran with the same user account as the one I was using Fiddler with.